# Python (Django) Class that aliases/overloads list index behavior to attributes

Tags: django, django-models, python

I have a class that stores information about a week:

```
from django.db import models

#A django model, so can't subclass list (at least not easily)
class MyWeek(models.Model):
    sunday    = "foo"
    monday    = "foo"
    tuesday   = "foo"
    wednesday = "foo"
    thursday  = "foo"
    friday    = "foo"
    saturday  = "foo"
```

I'd like to be able to access these attributes as if the class was a list:

```
aweek = Myweek()

#I want this
aweek[0] = "bar"
myvar = aweek[1]

#To be shorthand for this
aweek.monday = "bar"
myvar = aweek.tuesday

#and of course
aweek[7]
ValueError/IndexError: Week indexes monday to 0 and sunday to 6, there is no 7
```

Everything about python makes think this is possible and easy, if only I know the right set of things to overload.

I've thought of @property, but that doesn't help so much because I want to be able to use a variable to access it:

```
#I want to be able to do this
aweek[somevar] = "bar"

#and via property, i'd have to use exec
#and this is just ugly and scary from an "oh god, what could somevar be" perspective
exec("aweek.%s = 'bar'" % somevar)

#Or, as kojiro pointed out below, it could be done like this:
setattr(aweek, "somevar", "bar")
```

Thanks.

Edit:  Working code, hattip to kojiro for helping with the right methods to overload:

```
# overload []
def __getitem__(self, index):       
    index = int(index) #will raise value error if uncoercable, this is desired behavior
    if index < 0 or index > 6:
        raise ValueError("Requires an integer index between 0 and 6, monday is 0 sunday is 6")
    if index == 0:
        return self.monday
    elif index == 1:
        return self.tuesday
    elif index == 2:
        return self.wednesday
    elif index == 3:
        return self.thursday
    elif index == 4:
        return self.friday
    elif index == 5:
        return self.saturday
    elif index == 6:
        return self.sunday   

# overload set []
def __setitem__(self, index, item):
    index = int(index) #will raise value error if uncoercable, this is desired behavior
    if index < 0 or index > 6:
        raise ValueError("Requires an integer index between 0 and 6, monday is 0 sunday is 6")
    if index == 0:
        self.monday = item
        return
    elif index == 1:
        self.tuesday = item
        return
    elif index == 2:
        self.wednesday = item
        return
    elif index == 3:
        self.thursday = item
        return
    elif index == 4:
        self.friday = item
        return
    elif index == 5:
        self.saturday = item
        return
    elif index == 6:
        self.sunday = item
        return
```

Comment: By the way, you don't have to use `exec()` for the above. `setattr(aweek, "somevar", "bar")` will work just fine and is definitely preferable. [Read more](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: oh, nice.  I hadn't used setattr before, that's a much much better way of doing it, I'm going to use that in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a list-like object in python you need to create the following methods:

`__len__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__contains__`

[Link to explanatory example.](http://snipplr.com/view/6626/)

Comment: Or you could just inherit a class from ```list``` and override some fields from above.

Comment: @PavelShvedov good point, I should've said "you need…the following". You don't have to create them if you already have them. :)

Comment: @PavelShvedov.  subclassing list was my first instinct.  But, it is either impossible or not straight forward and error prone to inherit from list -- this is a django model class, so it HAS to inherit from models.Model.  Dual inheritance MIGHT be possible, but that's asking for logical rats-nests in the best case.

Comment: @Ted dual inheritance *is* possible, and to understand the logical rat's nest you need to understand [The Python MRO](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.3/mro/).